# Magento 2 CSS doesn't load

Tags: php, css, magento2, php-7

After reading any kind of solution, i need your help to solve my problem.
Magento 2.1.2, PHP7, Ubuntu. Fresh install, created new theme. When i switch to the new theme, this error appears even in frontend that in backend (backend shouldn't be a problem!):

Frontend error

[image]

Backend error

[image]

Already tried:

1. Switch back to original template
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
3. Set developer mode
4. var/cache and pub/static (less then .htaccess) cleaned
5. Ownership check (magento_user:www-data for all files), permissions ok

I think it's just amazing! I can understand any problem, but this is really strange. Why should the backend be affected by this problem? Why, even if i set mode developer, magento 2 tries to get some "static/_cache" CSS file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I hope, you have already found the solution for your issue but it
>   might be useful for future surfers.

The path for the frontend compilation in admin panel is given below:

```
Stores > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > Front-end development workflow
```

But, if there is an error in Backend panel as well then the listed issue can be resolved by running the `update` query in the database.

```
update core_config_data 
set value='server_side_compilation' 
where path = 'dev/front_end_development_workflow/type';
```